# How to implement Ajax calls in a Spring MVC JSP view

Tags: spring, jsp, model-view-controller

I'm doing a java MVC project using Maven, Spring and MySQL.

The fact is that I want to display a text message when I select a value on a "select" form and when I pick a date on a calendar.

I have the following code on my jsp view (this is only the core of the question)

```
        <div class="well lead">Formulario De Registro De Tarea</div>
    <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="task" class="form-horizontal">
        <form:input type="hidden" path="id" id="id"/>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="type">Tipo de tarea</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <select id="type" name="type">
                        <c:forEach var="item" items="${typesList}">
                            <option value="${item.type}">${item.type}</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="date">Fecha</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <form:input type="text" path="date" id="datepicker" style="width:100px" class="form-control input-sm"/> 
                    <div class="has-error">
                        <c:if test="${fechaFestivo != null}">
                            <p> ${fechaFestivo}</p>
                        </c:if>
                        <form:errors path="date" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="duration">Duración (horas)</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <form:input type="text" path="duration" id="duration" style="width:60px" class="form-control input-sm" />
                    <div class="has-error">
                        <c:if test="${duracionMaxima != null}">
                            <p> ${duracionMaxima}</p>
                        </c:if>
                        <form:errors path="duration" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

That looks like this:

[image]

[image]

What I would like to do it's when I choose an option from the select of **"Tipo de tarea"**, display a text below the select saying: *"The average duration of all tasks with that type is... (and the average number)"*.

Also, when I pick a date from the calendar, displaying a text under **"Duracion"** field saying: *"You actually have X hours (sum of durations) for THIS (the picked) date"*.

**EDITING with more information**

**TaskController: get and post of the create task jsp**

```
/**
 * This method will provide the medium to add a new task.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = { "/newtask" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String newTask(ModelMap model) {
    Task task = new Task();
    typesService.loadTypes();

    Collection<Types> typesList = typesService.findAllTypes();
    model.addAttribute("task", task);
    model.addAttribute("typesList", typesList);
    model.addAttribute("edit", false);
    model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
    return "task/register";
}

/**
 * This method will be called on form submission, handling POST request for
 * saving task in database. It also validates the task input
 */
@RequestMapping(value = { "/newtask" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveTask(@Valid Task task, BindingResult result,
        ModelMap model) {

    Collection<Task> dayTasks = taskService.findTasksDateUserType(task.getDate(), task.getDate(), getPrincipalUser().getId(), null);
    Double tasksDuration = taskService.getTasksDuration(dayTasks);

    if(task.getDuration()+tasksDuration>12.0) {
        ObjectError error = new ObjectError("duracionMaxima", "No se pueden incurrir más de 12 horas un mismo día");
        result.addError(error);
    }

    if(festivoService.isFestivo(task.getDate())) {
        ObjectError error = new ObjectError("fechaFestivo", "La fecha de la tarea es un día festivo");
        result.addError(error);
    }

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        Collection<Types> typesList = typesService.findAllTypes();
        //List<TaskType> typesList = new ArrayList<TaskType>(Arrays.asList(TaskType.values()));
        model.addAttribute("typesList", typesList);
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        for(ObjectError o: result.getAllErrors()) {
            System.out.println(o.getObjectName());
            if(o.getObjectName().equals("fechaFestivo")) {
                model.addAttribute("fechaFestivo", "La fecha de la tarea es un día festivo");
            }
            if(o.getObjectName().equals("duracionMaxima")) {
                model.addAttribute("duracionMaxima", "No se pueden incurrir más de 12 horas un mismo día");
            }
        }
        return "task/register";
    }

    if(task.getDate().after(new Date())){
        FieldError dateError =new FieldError("task","date",messageSource.getMessage("date.before", new String[]{}, Locale.getDefault()));
        result.addError(dateError);

        Collection<Types> typesList = typesService.findAllTypes();
        model.addAttribute("typesList", typesList);
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "task/register";
    }

    User user = getPrincipalUser();
    taskService.save(task,user);

    model.addAttribute("success", user.getName() + " ha registrado la tarea"+ task.getId() + " correctamente");
    model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
    //return "success";
    return "task/registerSuccess";
}
```

**AJAX RequestMapping:**
I have just done those methods for the AJAX calls

```
    @RequestMapping(value= {"/ajax/type-{id}"})
public Double ajaxType(@PathVariable Integer typeId) {
    return typesService.getAvgDailyEffort(typeId);
}

@RequestMapping(value= {"/ajax/date-{date}"})
public Double ajaxDate(@PathVariable String date) {
    Double result = 0.;
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    try {
        Date dateF = formatter.parse(date);
        Collection<Task> tasks = taskService.findTasksDateUserType(dateF, dateF, getPrincipalUser().getId(), null);
        result = taskService.getTasksDuration(tasks);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

I also have added this to my jsp view

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable"></label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <p id="avg"> Media de horas del tipo de tarea</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-lable"></label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <p id="durationday">Horas incurridas en la fecha</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now my JSP view looks like this:

[image]

What I would like to do after reading about jQuery it's to get the value from *"type"* (Tipo de tarea) and *"date"* (Fecha) when it changes, calculate what I previously described and replace the corresponding text with the calcuations' results.

**EDIT AGAIN**
Just added this code to my jsp head (jquery script)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#type").change(function(){
        $('#avg').load('/ajax-type', 
                "type="+$('#type').find('option').val())
    });
    $("#datepicker").change(function(){
        $('#durationday').load('/ajax-date', 
                "date="+$('#datepicker').val())
    });
});
```

And changed my controller methods to:

```
    @RequestMapping(value= {"/ajax-type"})
public @ResponseBody String ajaxType(@RequestParam("type") String type) {
    Collection<Types> types = typesService.findAllTypes();
    int typeId = 0;
    for(Types t: types) {
        if(t.getType().equals(type)) {
            typeId = t.getId();
        }
    }
    double avgDailyEffort = typesService.getAvgDailyEffort(typeId);
    return "Media de horas del tipo de tarea: " + avgDailyEffort;
}

@RequestMapping(value= {"/ajax-date"})
public @ResponseBody String ajaxDate(@RequestParam("date") String date) {
    Double tasksDuration = 0.;
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    try {
        Date dateF = formatter.parse(date);
        Collection<Task> tasks = taskService.findTasksDateUserType(dateF, dateF, getPrincipalUser().getId(), null);
        tasksDuration = taskService.getTasksDuration(tasks);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "Horas incurridas en la fecha: " + tasksDuration;
}
```

But I'm getting a GET 404 (not found) when I make a change on boths fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a client side technology such as javascript. A good javascript library called JQuery has good pre built functions for making ajax calls but you will need to do some research and try it out. If you get stuck I think you will need to ask a specific question relating to javascript (JQuery if you decide to use it). The following may help:
[Getting started with JQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp) and
[JQuery ajax api](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

With the extra info, firstly change `@RequestMapping(value= {"/ajax/type-{id}"})` to `@RequestMapping(value= {"/ajax/type/{id}"})` this will allow you to use the path variable (do the same for date). You will also need to add `@ResponseBody` straight after the request mapping and before the method declaration so spring knows to return the value.

Comment: Well, after reading all that information that you've given on your answer, I think I know what I want but I'm not able to do it by myself (or following a tutorial, because all of them are focused on listing, deleting or modifying objects with PHP). I just want to make a query with the value inserted to MySQL DB and print the result below the input using jQuery.

Comment: You need to set up some specific mappings in your controller for the ajax to call which return the required values/objects. `@RequestMapping("ajax")` etc if you can post your current controller it might be helpful to see your server side code.

Comment: Just edited my question with more code and explanations about what I'm trying to do, now it maybe looks more understandable with the new little knowledge about jQuery

Comment: Edited again with some changes I've just made with the new tips

Comment: I'm thinking on it now, maybe the spanish accent and de '/' on the dates could be creating conflicts?

Comment: Yes you would need to format the date differently to send by http

Comment: Also I think you need to include your query string in the url part of the load function. `$("#datepicker").change(function(){
        $('#durationday').load('/ajax-date?date='+$('#datepicker').val())
    });`

Comment: Great! just got it working right now, thanks a lot for all your help!!!!

Comment: No worries, as it was a mix of my answer and comments, if you can accept my answer that would be grand.